# Recursive Array in Knockout

Tags: recursion, knockout.js

I'm trying this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nonsense66/Bzekr/) recursive template but I'm stuck at dynamic data rendering. My data looks like:

```
[Object
    Children:    Array[2]
    EventCategory: Object
]
```

So far I have this template as per jsfiddle example but how to check if the array has child?

```
    <script id="categoryTemplate" type="text/html">
        //How to check if data has child and display the child to its parent?
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'categoryTemplate', foreach: children }"></ul>
        </li>
    </script>
```

Html rendering:

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'categoryTemplate', foreach: $data.categoryRoot}"></ul>
```

Knockout binding, how to render the array?

```
var categoryElement = function (name, children) {
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(children);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

var categoryModel = {
    categoryRoot: ko.observableArray()
};

var viewModel = function () {
    var me = this;
    me.categoryRoot = ko.observableArray();

        me.selectCategory = function () {
            $.get('link-to-get-categories').then(function(response) {
                var categoryData = [
                //new categoryElement("Russia", [
                //    new categoryElement("Moscow")
                //]),
                new categoryElement(response.Data)

                //me.categoryRoot(categoryData);
                me.categoryRoot(response.Data);
            });
        }
}

ko.cleanNode($('#addEvent')[0]);
ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new viewModel(), $('#addEvent')[0]);
```

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your data, that's useless. Post your data.

Comment: It's just showing how my data structure looks like

Comment: I know, but pasting the *actual data* is infinitely more useful than a static screenshot of your browser console. So next time, please simply post your data.

Comment: Please upvote the helpful answers and accept one of them. StackOverflow is not a forum where you can walk away after your question has been answered. Upvoting is the way to say "thank you", marking an answer as accepted is the way to close the thread.

Comment: @Tomalak as of this writing I did not got the answer I'm looking for but I got it working anyway. Thanks

Comment: If you didn't get the answer you were looking for it would be polite to discuss suggested solutions via the comments. Generally questions are answered as they have been asked. Your question was *"How to check if data has child and display the child to its parent?"* and that question has been answered in more than one way. That you ended up using something else in your actual code is completely irrelevant to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptional mistake: Your tree root is not itself a list. It's a single tree element. In other words, don't use an array for the tree root.

I'd also flip the tree building template around so that it's completely self-contained.

Apart from that, knockout's virtual elements and the `if` binding can sort out the conditional rendering.

```js
var TreeElement = function(name, children) {
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(children);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
};

var viewModel = {
    treeRoot: new TreeElement(null, [
        new TreeElement("Russia", [
            new TreeElement("Moscow")
        ]),
        new TreeElement("Germany"),
        new TreeElement("United States", [
            new TreeElement("Atlanta"),
            new TreeElement("New York", [
                new TreeElement("Harlem"),
                new TreeElement("Central Park")
            ])
        ]),
        new TreeElement("Canada", [
            new TreeElement("Toronto")
        ])
    ])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.tree {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script id="tree" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko if: children().length -->
    <ul class="tree" data-bind="foreach: children">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <!-- ko template: 'tree' --><!-- /ko -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'tree', data: treeRoot}"></div>
```

Comment: based on your snippet, the `treeRoot` value I'm getting stuck at, how am I suppose to load the dynamic value of this based on `response.Data` screenshot?

Comment: I'm guessing `treeRoot: new TreeElement(null, response.Data)` -  assuming that `response.Data` is an array. The `TreeElement` constructor should then take care of creating its own child `TreeElement` objects.

Answer (score 0):

> how to check if the array has child?

You can check for children in a data-bind like so:

```
<-- ko if: children().length -->
<ul></ul>
<-- /ko -->
```

Simplify the data-bind by creating a computed in your viewmodel:

```
self.hasChildren = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return self.children().length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<-- ko if: children && children().length -->
<ul></ul>
<-- /ko --> Safe check
```